# Access wiring of ceiling can light without overhead access

Tags: electrical, ceiling, recessed-lighting

I have first floor old school recessed can lights in my kitchen that I want to replace with LED clip-in wafer lights. I do not want to install the LED retrofits. How do I access the wiring of the can light without overhead access?

I understand there are 3 screws in the side of the can that I can unscrew and nudge the can to the side in the ceiling cavity but I’m not sure how to open up the junction box and “remove” or get enough of the electrical wire to wire it into a new wafer driver box.

Comment: A picture of the can light guts in question might be helpful, here.

Answer (score 2):

The details will vary a bit with the **specific** can light, but you more-or-less disassemble the can in the hole to gain access to the junction box. At that point you have a 6" (or 4") hole to work through so you should be able to see (possibly with the help of a cell phone camera) what means were provided to open the junction box, which also vary a bit with the **specific** can light. Many open on both sides (so the outside when newly installing, and the inside when accessing through the removed can hole.)

Given the things meet code, you CAN access the junction box. But given dozens of manufacturers (at least) and hundreds of different models over the years, how is going to be specific to yours rather than some generic "you take out 3 screws and..."

Comment: Perhaps the OP can remove the bulb and any fairing, and provide a picture of what he sees.