# Install canless LED fixture in new construction can housing?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

I have two new construction Halo 4" (H99ICAT) recessed housings installed in my bathroom renovation. Drywall is up, and I started looking at fixtures. Some of the ones I like the look of are canless and include their own junction box. Is there a code-compliant way to wire these for use inside a new construction can housing, or am I limited to using screw-in retrofit fixtures with an integrated driver only? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/267426/18078

Comment: Agreed, @Ecnerwal. You _can_ VtC...

Comment: @FreeMan I have, unasked for, 1-vote close in several tags, though some mechanism like having 1000 points in the tag badge or something. I'm not really fond of it, and it's made me cautious about VtC where there isn't an egregious reason to VtC. Not sure it that even applies to either of these tags, but there's no warning or caution or selectivity about it when it does apply. Would be nice if it brought up a little dialog box so you could choose to make it a regular close vote. Not being a ravening dictator-type, I prefer consensus closing.

Comment: Fair enough, @Ecnerwal. You can, of course, reopen the question if you accidentally close it single-handedly. ;)

Comment: It's asymmetric, though. I can vote to reopen and 2(?) (not sure how many reopen votes are required, actually) other people also have to, even if I alone closed it. And I was of the opinion it should be closed, to at least 1/3 of closing it, if 2 other people with "cast close vote" agreed.